# How can i use xunit (.net core) test results in jenkins?

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core, xunit

I have an asp.net core application that has some tests written in XUnit. How can i use the test results with a tool like jenkins?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i struggled with this issue so i decided to share my answer based on my experience.

In order to use the test results, we need to output them into XML files that can be used later by a parser. The xml needs to be in the format that the parser knows how to read.

By default, when running [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore2x), it will output the test results into the console. In order to save those results into a file, we should use the "--logger" param. the logger param can accept a logger than will parse the test results into the desired format. in order to parse them into an xunit xml test files that can be used by tools like jenkins, we need to use an external logger named [XunitXml.TestLogger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XunitXml.TestLogger). Now we can run the following command:

```
dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:xunit
```

that will export the results into a *TestResults* folder in each project you have.
now we can use these files by any tool, like jenkins to parse those files. jenkins has a plugin named [Xunit](https://plugins.jenkins.io/xunit) (how original) that does specifically that. it even lets you set some error thresholds etc.

Update: fegarding jenkins, i have found out that there are plugins that allow you to convert dot TRX results (that dotnet knows to export natively) to XUnit format. that might simplify it and save you that extra dependency. MSTest if one of those - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin

Comment: I get an error "Could not find a test logger with AssemblyQualifiedName, URI or FriendlyName 'xunit'" Any ideas why?

Comment: @pogorman it sounds like XunitXml.TestLogger was not installed. try exporting the results without the xunit logger (just run the command without the --logger:xunit part), if it succeeds, there is probably an issue with the XunitXml.TestLogger

Comment: that was it - I needed to install XunitXml.TestLogger on each test project, thank you